# Openshift: where to put resource files that I want outside of the deployment folder

Tags: openshift

I'm starting a new web app with Openshift (jboss, mysql). It's the first time I use openshift and after reading through some doc and experimenting a bit with it, I'm having one question regarding best practices for the architecture of my app.

There will be some files generated by- or uploaded to the application (resources). I'd like those files to be outside the deployment folder so they are not erased/overwritten when the app deploys again. I have browsed through the directories and I was wondering:

is it ok to use the **/var/lib/openshift/[openshift-id]/app-root/data** folder for these files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should use your ~/app-root/data folder for any files that you want to not be erased when you do a git push, there is also an environment variable that you can use that points to that folder called OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR.  Please note that if you are using a scaled application, that folder is not shared among your gears.

Comment: You have 1 GB of storage available on the free plan on each gear.